# Mouse disappears on the lower half of my screen (ubuntu 16.04.02 with xfce)

Tags: mouse, xfce

The mouse disappears on the lower half of my screen. It happened a while back after an update (not sure which) and I've just left it thinking that another update might fix it. A while has gone by, and it hasn't fixed itself, so I was thinking of just re-installing Xubuntu.

However, when I went to use Kodi the other day the mouse magically reappeared on the lower half of the screen again. Now I'm thinking that the problem could be with the window manager? It must be something to do with the display manager (I might be using poor terminology). Also, even though the mouse is not visible it is still possible to click on things (if you happen to get lucky and land just over the button).

What should I do?